# reducing execution time of this query

Tags: mysql

Can any help me to optimize this query below?

```
Select id,name 
from tb_demo t1 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (Select id 
     from tb_demo 
     WHERE time > now() 
         AND id = t1.id) 
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't

```
SELECT id, name
from tb_demo
where time > now()
group by id
```

Work for you?

the nested select isn't necessary.

Comment: ya i need nesting cos am trying to simulate other table which the same contents with time field greater than now()

Comment: @somu.web why would you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

there is no much to optimize here on the query for me.

the only things you can do are:

1 - Caching query if possible

2 - Be sure you have id field as table INDEX

3 - Check all table fields and reduce their length when possible ( if you have a field that 
should be long 40/50 chars do not use length more then 50)